# Accessing previously created folder with oauth Google Drive

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

We are building an app that allows users to connect their cloud storage (in this case gDrive) and upload files from our app, however they also have the ability to disconnect from it and perhaps connect to another.

A use-case might be:

A User connects to gDrive(App creates folder and uploads files) >
Later user disconnects from drive in-app >
Later user reconnects

Problem being we then want to grab this previously created folder and make changes and the issue is, in order for the user to reconnect they have to reauthorize, setting a new token and we therefore no longer have access to that folder and instead our app auto-creates a new folder with the same name - obviously this is not what we want.

The only solutions we can think of is not re-authorizing on disconnect/connect or increasing the scope of oauth and searching for the folder.

We will be using something like [rClone](https://rclone.org/) in the future, but for now we are focusing on a couple of the main cloud services.

Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: Could you please share the relevant parts of the code you're using? I don't understand the connection between `reauthorize` and `no longer have access to that folder`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that. The connection is, when the user disconnects they unauthorize access to our app and when they connect again this requires reauthorizing. This gives us a new token and because our scope is limited to the folder we created, we no longer have access to it and have to create a new folder. We want to have access to the one that already exists, preferably without increasing scope - which is why I'm asking if there is any other way.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're using `DRIVE.FILE` scope. Unfortunately yes, I think in this case the only options are using a more powerful scope and changing the app workflow so that users don't deauthorize the app. Regarding the use of another scope, there is currently an open feature request to restrict the access to a certain folder on the user's Drive, [check it out](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760598).

Comment: Thought as much, thanks! Interesting link too!

Comment: You're welcome. I think questions should have answers, even if these answers are basically "You can't do that" (others might have the same question as you, and comments are not read that much). Because of this, I posted an answer.

Comment: Totally agree, marked yours as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your app is using [drive.file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) scope, which allows it to access files created or opened by the app.
- Users commonly disconnect from the app, effectively deauthorizing it. Because of this, the app does not have access to folders that were created last time user connected to the app.

The description of `drive.file` scope is quite clear:

> Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis **and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app**.

Because of this, unfortunately, the only two ways to allow the app to access previously created folders are the ones you already sketched:

- Use a scope that provides a wider access: the scope in this case should probably be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, since the app, from what I understand, needs write access.
- Change the workflow of your app so that users don't deauthorize the app.

Regarding the use of a wider scope, the following feature request, which apparently was internalized recently, could provide an acceptable workaround in case it got implemented:

- [FR: Drive Restrict access to folder when authorizing applications](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760598)

I'd suggest you to star the referenced issue, to keep track of its development and to help prioritizing it.